# Swapping option boxes in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

My client asked me (a JavaScript client-side programmer) to change the order of the options so that their company's option appears at the top of a select box when the page loads.

The following code works in Firefox but fails in Internet Explorer 7 when I try to swap two options:

```
    function load{
        var shippingLocation  = document.getElementById("location");
        var swap = null;

        var initiallyFirstItem = shippingLocation.options[0].cloneNode(true);

        var lastPos = null;

        for(var i = 0; i < shippingLocation.length; i++)
        {
            if(shippingLocation.options[i].value == "XETEX")
            {
                swap = shippingLocation.options[i];
                lastPos = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        console.debug("sl: " + shippingLocation.options[0]);
        console.debug("s: " + swap);
        shippingLocation.options[0] = swap;
        shippingLocation.options[lastPos] = initiallyFirstItem;
        shippingLocation.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

I get an error on the next to the third line from the bottom:

```
shippingLocation.options[0] = swap;
```

The error states that "object doesn't support this property or method".

What's Internet Explorer's beef with switching option items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did some testing and I believe that IE considers the options array as immutable (in a way). You can edit the options and you can remove them but you can't set one option to another.

So when you do this:

```
  shippingLocation.options[0] = swap;
```

IE is complaining because you're trying to set one option to another.

I would do this instead:

```
> Removed due to excessive stupidity on
> my part. :P
```

Here's a better way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function swap(obj,i,j) {
    sib=obj.options[i].nextSibling;
    obj.insertBefore(obj.options[i],obj.options[j]);
    obj.insertBefore(obj.options[j],sib);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah here we go.  Much more elegant than the code above.

```
function swapOptions(obj,i,j){
    var o = obj.options;
    var i_selected = o[i].selected;
    var j_selected = o[j].selected;
    var temp = new Option(o[i].text, o[i].value, o[i].defaultSelected, o[i].selected);
        var temp2= new Option(o[j].text, o[j].value, o[j].defaultSelected, o[j].selected);
    o[i] = temp2;o[j] = temp;o[i].selected = j_selected;o[j].selected = i_selected;
}
```